# Sending location to server with CLLocationManager when iphone is in background

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager

i'm having trouble sending my position when the application lies in the background. I'm using CLLocationManager and startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges. The posision didUpdateToLocation delegate method is performed once, but not more. I've tried to walk around but no new locations is sent to the server.

I have set the "Required background modes" -> "App registers for location updates" in the info.plist file.

Anyone got an idea on what might be wrong?

**Code from where the tracking is started:**

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = appDelegate;
[appDelegate setLocationManager:locationManager withDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
[appDelegate.theLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

**Code (from CLLocationManagerDelegate):**

```
- (void)setLocationManager:(CLLocationManager*)locationManager withDistanceFilter:(CLLocationDistance)distanceFilter {

    // create a new manager and start checking for sig changes
    self.theLocationManager.delegate = nil;
    [theLocationManager release];

    self.theLocationManager = locationManager;
    self.theLocationManager.delegate = self;
    self.theLocationManager.distanceFilter = distanceFilter;
}


    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

        NSDate *newLocationTimestamp = newLocation.timestamp;
        NSDate *oldLocationTimestamp = oldLocation.timestamp;

        int locationUpdateInterval = 15;//15 sec

        if (!([newLocationTimestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:oldLocationTimestamp] < locationUpdateInterval)) {
                //NSLog(@"New Location: %@", newLocation);
                [self updateToLocation:newLocation];
        }

    }

    - (void)updateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation {
        NSLog(@"update location!!");

        NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [newLocation coordinate].latitude];
         NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [newLocation coordinate].longitude];

        [currentUser updatePositionWithLongitude:longitude andLatitude:latitude]; 
    }
```

Comment: how far did you walk around? Depending on your location, you may need to cover more significant distance

Comment: hm, not far.. I'll try to test it by walking further. 1km or so should be sufficient or ?

Comment: perhaps just swap out `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` for `startUpdatingLocation` and see if it behaves as expected...then you'll rule out problems elsewhere

Comment: from what I've read, one big dependency is the cell tower density, so if you're in an urban area, 1km may be plenty, but if you're in a more rural area, that might not suffice

Comment: Ok, i'll try walking a bit longer...

Comment: I've tried "startUpdatingLocation" and that works.. But that doesn't work when the application is in background if what i've read is correct.

Comment: no, it does work in background, but may not be worth it from a battery perspective

Comment: Tried walking about 1km but without success, the coordinates isn't sent to the server :/ I'll try experimenting a bit more with startUpdatingLocation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Bill Brasky said, the accuracy to which you have set your location manager is likely not registering the distance that you have walked. Try setting your location manager accuracy much higher, just to see if works, then dial it back down to a happy medium between accuracy and battery efficiency. Just for testing, take it all the way up:

```
[appDelegate.theLocationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
```

Then instead of:

```
[appDelegate.theLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

try:

```
[appDelegate.theLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm now using startUpdatingLocation and it works as intended. I still have to adjust it a bit because of battery efficiency but i'll get it right eventually :)

Answer (score 2):

The -startMonitoringForSignificantLocationChanges is directly tied to cell tower connectivity. You may need to travel miles to get connection to a new tower and trigger a location change event. I know that the region monitoring is a bit more accurate as it uses updates of location from Wifi, cell tower, and even other apps that inquire on location. You will need to figure out how accurate and how often you need your app to be. You may need to actively monitor location in the background (which would be a battery killer for sure). Hope this helps.